# Ignore blank cell to format in python xlsxwriter

Tags: python, excel, automation, xlsxwriter

I am using xlsxwriter module to format a excel file. I have blank cell in one column and I don not want to format those empty cell. How can do it?

```
worksheet.conditional_format('F1:F12', {'type': 'cell', 'criteria': '<=', 'value': 0, 'format': bold})
```

this format is applicable for entire column but I don not want to include empty cell in this format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To figure out a conditional format in XlsxWriter you should figure it out in Excel first and then transfer it across.

In this case you have more than one criteria so it is probably best to use a formula. Something like this:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('conditional_format.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Add a format. Light red fill with dark red text.
format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE',
                               'font_color': '#9C0006'})


# Write some sample data.
data = [1, 0, 2, -1, "", -1, "", 1]
worksheet.write_column(0, 0, data)


# Write a conditional format over a range.
worksheet.conditional_format(0, 0, len(data) -1, 0,
                             {'type': 'formula',
                              'criteria': '=AND(A1<=0,A1<>"")',
                              'value': 0,
                              'format': format1})

workbook.close()
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: what is the meaning of `A1<>""` in the `'criteria': '=AND(A1<=0,A1<>"")'`?

Comment: It means “A1 is not blank”. Excel has a `ISBLANK()` function that could be used instead, in conjunction with `NOT()`.

Comment: How can i use this function for one column? Let's Assume here A1:A8

Comment: I don’t understand. The example shows it working on A1:A8 (as row, column values). You can also use an Excel style string range as shown in the xlsxwriter docs.

Comment: I mean you are using this formula only for A1 ```'criteria': '=AND(A1<=0,A1<>"")'``` how can i use for the range of cells like A1:A8?

Comment: It is already working over the full range. Cell reference in conditional formats work the same way as they do in formulas that you put in one cell and drag to other cells. Vertically `A1` changes to `A2`, `A3`, etc. Alternatively `$A$1` doesn't change and the formulas always references `A1`. And `$A1` and `A$1` lock the column and row numbers, respectively. You probably need to read up on how conditional formatting works in Excel, or as suggested above, figure out how it works in Excel. Trying to figure it out from first principles using xlsxwriter probably isn't the best way to do it.